# Mysql client login without any authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords

I installed mysql 5.7.11 from repo.mysql.com.
I pressed all installation and create new debian image. after installation mysql dont need password. I can connect to mysql with "mysql -u root" and "mysql -u root -p" and with any password
I change root password multiple times and exec flush privileges, but ther problem exist

Comment: I found that this problem with root only. in mysql 5.5 root dont access to database without password but with this version i can access without password. What is change in this version?

Answer (score 1):

problem form my pressed.cfg syntax. Corrct one is

```
mysql-community-server  mysql-community-server/root-pass password passwod_string
mysql-community-server  mysql-community-server/root-pass seen true
mysql-community-server  mysql-community-server/re-root-pass passwod password_string
mysql-community-server  mysql-community-server/re-root-pass seen true
```